# How to get the particular checked checkboxes, generated dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dynamic

I have div in which i append dynamic widgets that each contains a checkbox at the toolbar. This checkbox is use to control the widget, therefore i have set a serial numbers which are dynamically set as ids. Each one is unique so i think they are good for ids.

The problem now is how can i retrieve the exact id of the checked checkbox.
This returns the id of the last checkbox in the div as it loop uncontrollably.

I have a spinet below:

```
for (var i=0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

$("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("
<div class='col-xs-12  col-sm-6 widget-container-col'>"
    +"
    <div class='widget-box widget-color-blue'>"
        +"
        <div class='widget-header'>"
            +"<h5 class='widget-title bigger lighter'>"+sortedIds[i]+"</h5>"
            +"
            <div class='widget-toolbar'>"
                +"
                <div class='ontrol-group'>"
                    +"
                    <div class='checkbox'>"
                        +"<label class='block'>"
                            +"<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget'
                                     id=''/>"
                            +"<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>"
                            +" </label>"
                        +"
                    </div>
                    "
                    +"
                </div>
                "
                +"
            </div>
            "
            +"
        </div>
        "
        +"
        <div class='widget-body'>"
            +"
            <div class='widget-main'>"
                +"
                <div class='test_list_wraper'></div>
                "
                +"
            </div>
            "
            +"
        </div>
        "
        +"
    </div>
    "
    +"
</div>");                                                         

$("[name='form-field-checkbox']").attr("id",sortedIds[i]);

}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can use backticks instead of quotes to include newlines in a string, or you can escape newlines with a backslash

Comment: Thanks but not sure how it is done.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, sorry, that was just something unrelated that save you some typing :)

Answer (score -1):

If those are the only checkboxes on your page, you can also do something like this:

```
var checkArray = [];
$('input.comic-check').each(function() {
    checkArray.push($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

Comment: Sir, it gives me the last checkbox id in the batch_schedule_wraper div.     I have used this:             var selected = [];
            
            $("div#batch_schedule_wraper input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    }                
            });   alert(selected);

Comment: This'll iterate over every checkbox in your DOM. You might only be saving the last one? Try something like above (I edited my answer)

Comment: `id` is not a css property

Comment: Oops, just copied and pasted some old code of mine and forgot to change it to attr. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlietfl you are right, and of course i have repeated the same sortedIds value to reflect as a text in the <h5> and as an id in the checkbox. If i really save the "Last one" as JonLuca said then, the <h5> text will all be the same. Please look at the snippet  more closely.

Comment: Here is the output link https://ibb.co/kD7P05  only the last checkbox id is pushed into array.